Filter two lists based on multiple filter criteria and add additional information from a third list to the results
Data Source



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q




1
List A




List B




List C








2
date
brand
prod.
val.

date
br.
prod.
val.

prod.

country
channel

type
line


3
2022-05-10
Br_A
P1
15

2022-0-15
Br_B
P2
17

P1

DE
local

t3
l2


4
2023-01-15
Br_A
P1
18

2023-02-15
Br_B
P1
25

P2

NL
web

t2
l2


5
2022-08-12
Br_B
P2
30

2023-10-18
Br_B
P1
38

P3

US
web

t2
l2


6
2022-09-15
Br_B
P2
50

2023-11-19
Br_B
P1
12

P4

AT
local

t1
l3


7
2023-06-15
Br_B
P3
20

2023-12-15
Br_B
P2
41

P5

FR
web

t3
l1


8
2023-06-18
Br_B
P1
80

2024-05-18
Br_B
P1
2

P6

PL
local

t1
l1


9
2024-05-17
Br_B
P4
25

2024-09-30
Br_B
P4
10










10
2022-08-19
Br_C
P3
85

2022-10-15
Br_E
P2
35










11
2022-09-30
Br_C
P3
70

2023-09-18
Br_E
P2
28










12
2024-04-25
Br_C
P3
32

2023-09-18
Br_E
P3
22










13
2025-08-29
Br_D
P1
45

2024-10-19
Br_E
P3
38










14
2022-03-25
Br_E
P2
60















15
2022-03-26
Br_E
P2
85















16
2024-05-20
Br_E
P3
90















17
2024-06-03
Br_E
P4
15















18
2024-07-30
Br_E
P4
26
















Expected Result:



0
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
AA




1

Filter_01

Br_B








2

Filter_02

2023-12-31








3












4

Result










5

prod.

channel
country

line
type

val.


6

P2

web
NL

l2
t2

22 (=30+50-17-41)


7

P3

web
US

l2
t3

20


8

P1

local
De

l2
t3

5 (=80-25-38-12)





In the List C (Column K to Column Q) are different prod. and their general information listed. 
In List A (Column A to Column D) you can see when the prod. were bought. 
In List B (Column F to Column I) you can see when the prod. were sold. 


In the expected result in Range S6:AA8 I want to
1. Filter the prod. from List A and List B based on the filter criteria: 
Cell U1 --> (=brand) 
Cell U2 --> (<=date) 
2. The order of the filtered list should be ascending based on the date from List A. 
3. Subtract the val. per prod. in List B from List A 
4. Add detailed information about the filtered prod. from List C to it. 
(!) There are empty columns in Range S6:AA8 and the order from the columns in List C is different. (!)

So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=LET(
filter_list_a,IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,B:B=U1),""),
filter_list_b,IFERROR(FILTER(H:H,G:G=U1),""),
p,UNIQUE(VSTACK(filter_list_a,filter_list_b)),
HSTACK(p,MAP(p,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,x,B:B,U1)-SUMIFS(I:I,H:H,x,G:G,U1)))))

This formula almost gives me the correct values. 
However, it is missing the filter in Cell U2, the additional information from List C and does not consider the empty columns in Range S6:AA8. 
Do you have any idea how to change the formula to get the expected result in Range S6:AA8?
The solution does not have to be in one formula. It is also fine if it is split in one formula that filters the prod. and another formula that attaches the details from List C do it.

Note:

The prod. in List C are always unique. 
In List A and List B there can never appear a prod. that is not existing in List C. 
In List B there can never appear a prod. that is not existing in List A. 
Both in List A and List B the combination date+brand+prod. is always unique.
The name of the headers in List A, List B, List C and in Range S6:AA8 are always the same.


If you do not have the requisite functions, I have added a Power Query solution to my answer which may be useful.

If I understand it correctly, this is what you're after:
=LET(x,VSTACK(A3:D18,HSTACK(F3:H13,-I3:I13)),
     c,CHOOSECOLS,
     z,LAMBDA(y,XLOOKUP(c(x,3),K3:K8,y)),
GROUPBY(HSTACK(c(x,3),
               z(N3:N8),
               z(M3:M8),
               z(Q3:Q8),
               z(P3:P8)),
        c(x,4),
        SUM,
        ,
        0,
        ,
        (c(x,2)=U1)*(c(x,1)<=U2)))

x first stacks the data and the data you want subtracted.
z is a lambda function inside the function to XLOOKUP the prod values of x and return the accompanying values in the input range of the lambda.
Next we HSTACK the 3rd column from x and the z lookup results for the columns you want added to the output and use them as the row fields of GROUPBY and use the values from the 4th column of x and use the filter argument to only include the required values.
Link to file including formula in S11
And sorted per matching date in list A:
=LET(x,VSTACK(A3:D18,HSTACK(F3:H13,-I3:I13)),c,CHOOSECOLS,z,LAMBDA(y,XLOOKUP(c(x,3),K3:K8,y)),g,GROUPBY(HSTACK(c(x,3),z(N3:N8),z(M3:M8),z(Q3:Q8),z(P3:P8)),c(x,4),SUM,,0,,(c(x,2)=U1)*(c(x,1)<=U2)),SORTBY(g,XLOOKUP(U1&"|"&c(g,1),c(x,2)&"|"&c(x,3),c(x,1))))

S16 is the sorted version
Avoiding GROUPBY:
=LET(a,VSTACK(SORT(A3:D18),HSTACK(F3:H13,-I3:I13)),b,FILTER(a,(INDEX(a,,2)=U1)*(INDEX(a,,1)<=U2)),c,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(b,2,3)),REDUCE(HSTACK(C2,N2,M2,Q2,P2,D2),SEQUENCE(ROWS(c)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,INDEX(c,y,2),v,LAMBDA(w,VLOOKUP(z,K3:Q8,w)),VSTACK(x,HSTACK(z,v(4),v(3),v(7),v(6),SUM((INDEX(b,,2)=INDEX(c,y,1))*(INDEX(b,,3)=INDEX(c,y,2))*INDEX(b,,4))))))))

Thanks for your answer. I do not have the GROUPBY function yet available in my Excel. Is there an alternative way without it?

What version do you use 2021?

I use Office365. Version 2409.

I believe you can update, so groupby is available, I added a version avoiding groupby though. Not sure if you currently have CHOOSECOLS though. Let me know.

I have CHOOSECOLS. When I put your second formula I get the error that there is a parentheses missing. Do you have the same error on your side?

All versions should be in linked file

@Michi you are using German version, may be you need to change the commas to semicolon or dot per your regional settings, hope you remember this last time you had same problem

Everything works now.

Everything as in the REDUCE version, or also the GROUPBY versions?

I found retaining the sort order as per the request to be the most difficult part.
I also chose to use Tables as I find it less confusing than trying to keep track of all the column addresses (but you could change it back if you prefer). Tables also has the advantage of being to easily add/remove data without having to edit your formula.
To retain the sort order per column A sorted by dates, I added a sorted list with a numeric sort to use in the GroupBy function.
I Named the tables List_A, List_B and List_C
I also used Named Ranges for the Filter arguments.
=LET(
    A, SORT(List_A, 1),
    B, HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(List_B, 1, 2, 3), -TAKE(List_B, , -1)),
    _C, List_C,
    d, VSTACK(A, B),
    f, FILTER(d, (CHOOSECOLS(d, 1) <= Filter_02) * (CHOOSECOLS(d, 2) = Filter_01)),
    prod, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(f, 3)),
    sort, HSTACK(prod, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(prod))),
    as, HSTACK(
        f,
        XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(f, 3), CHOOSECOLS(sort, 1), CHOOSECOLS(sort, 2))
    ),
    g, GROUPBY(CHOOSECOLS(as, 5), CHOOSECOLS(as, 4), SUM, 0, 0),
    prods, XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(g, 1), CHOOSECOLS(sort, 2), CHOOSECOLS(sort, 1)),
    vals, CHOOSECOLS(g, 2),
    country, XLOOKUP(prods, CHOOSECOLS(_C, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_C, 3)),
    channel, XLOOKUP(prods, CHOOSECOLS(_C, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_C, 4)),
    type, XLOOKUP(prods, CHOOSECOLS(_C, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_C, 6)),
    line, XLOOKUP(prods, CHOOSECOLS(_C, 1), CHOOSECOLS(_C, 7)),
    blank, MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(prods), 1, LAMBDA(r, c, "")),
    result, VSTACK(
        {"prod.", "", "channel", "country", "", "line", "type", "", "val"},
        HSTACK(prods, blank, channel, country, blank, line, type, blank, vals)
    ),
    result
)



Edit: Alternative Power Query Solution
This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Format your three lists as Tables (Home => Format as Table) and either accept the default name or give them your own name.  I chose the same names as noted above
Name your Filters (I used the same names as above)

Make note of the table names


Select some cell in one of your Tables
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table and Filter names in the first section (Name="TableName") back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm
Note that when you create a table (eg for ListC) default names will be created for the blank columns. You can re-define them either here or in the PQ editor, but all columns must have unique names.

For appearance, you could redefine them as non-printing characters.



let

//Read in the data
//Edit "Name="tablename" entries as approriate
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="List_A"]}[Content],
        List_A = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1, List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source1),{type date,type text,type text, type number}})),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="List_B"]}[Content],
        List_B = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source2),{type date,type text,type text, type number}})),
    Source3 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="List_C"]}[Content],
        List_C = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source3, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source3), each {_, type nullable text})),
    BRAND =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filter_01"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    maxDate= Date.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filter_02"]}[Content][Column1]{0}),


//Combine List A and negative value List B
//Rename columns to be identical
    colNames = {"date","brand","product","value"},
    #"Rename List_A" = Table.RenameColumns(List_A, List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(List_A), colNames})),
    #"Rename List_B" = Table.RenameColumns(List_B, List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(List_B), colNames})),
    #"List_B Negative Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Rename List_B", {"value", each _*-1, Int64.Type}),

//Combine tables with List_A sorted by date
    #"Combine Tables" = Table.Combine({Table.Sort(#"Rename List_A", {"date", Order.Ascending}), #"List_B Negative Values"}),

//Filter the table per your filters
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Combine Tables", each [date] < maxDate and [brand] = BRAND),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"product"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([value]), type nullable number}}),

//combine with List_C
    #"Join C" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows","product", List_C,"prod.","Joined", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

//Add Index column to retain proper sort order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Join C", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index", "Joined", {"Column1", "country", "channel", "Column2", "type", "line"}),
    #"Add blank column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Joined", "   ", each null, type any),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Add blank column",{"product", "Column1", "channel", "country", "Column2", "line", "type", "   ", "Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Remove Index Col" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),

//For appearances, could easily rename the blank column headers to some non-visible characters or other name
//  or remove this step if you defined them when you created the table
    #"Rename 2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Remove Index Col",{{"Column1"," "}, {"Column2","  "}})
in 
    #"Rename 2"

Here is the output given your data:

